# Cycle Decomposition as Colored-Edges? How?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, permutations, coloring, graph-isomorphism

In a proposition of graph isomorphism I find that for a generator $σ \in S$ (the set of generator of a group), edges can be added to a directed edge-colored graph $X(G)$ of color $σ$ corresponding to the cycle decomposition of $σ$.

I don't understand the process of adding color-edges to a directed edge-colored graph, where  can I find such construction? Can any one provide an example?

The problem is found in a Ph.d. thesis. Before you go to the detail, you need 2 definitions:

> We denote the set of G to H isomorphisms by $ISO(G, H)$. We say $G$
> and $H$ are isomorphic (and write $G \cong H)$ if $ISO(G, H)$ is not
> empty.
>
> Given two finite sets Ω and ∆, if $G ≤ Sym(Ω)$ and $H ≤ Sym(∆)$ are
> permutation groups, then a bijection $π: Ω \to ∆$ is a permutational
> isomorphism from $G$ to $H$ if $G^π = H$. We denote the set of all $G$
> to $H$ permutational isomorphisms by $PISO(G, H)$.

Now see the proposition:

> Proposition. Given two transitive permutation groups $G, H ≤ S_n$, and
> an isomorphism $φ \in ISO(G, H)$, we can list the (at most $n$)
> permutational isomorphisms $π \in PISO(G, H)$ corresponding to $φ$ in
> time $O(n^3)$.
>
> Proof. Pick a set of generators $S ⊆ G$ for $G$; then $S^φ$ is the
> corresponding set of generators for $H$. We construct two directed
> edge-colored graphs $X(G)$, and $X(H)$, over the vertex set $[n]$.
>
> **For each generator $σ \in S$, we add to $X(G)$ edges of color $σ$**
> **corresponding to the cycle decomposition of $σ$.**
>
> Similarly for every $σ \in S$, we add to $X(H)$ edges of color $σ$
> corresponding to the cycle decomposition of $σ^φ ( \in S^φ )$.
>
> (Graph) Isomorphisms of $X(G)$ and $X(H)$ are permutational
> isomorphisms between $G$ and $H$; and we can test isomorphism of these
> colored graphs in linear time. Recall that isomorphisms of colored
> graphs preserve the colors by definition.
>
> To test isomorphism of these graphs, pick any vertex $x$ in $X(G)$,
> and run breadth first search starting at $x$ (because the groups are
> transitive, the choice will not matter). We assign to every vertex the
> unique word corresponding to the color of the path to that vertex in
> the BFS. Now repeat the same process for $X(H)$. If the labelings of
> the vertices do not yield a bijection, then reject. Otherwise check
> whether the bijection is indeed an isomorphism of the two graphs. The
> running time is linear in the size of the graphs.
>
> To list all permutational isomorphisms corresponding to  $φ$, we need
> to try every possible choice of root vertex $x$ for the $BFS$.
> Therefore the total running time will be n times linear in the size of
> the graphs. The graphs have $O(n^2)$ edges, since there is always a
> set of at most $2n$ generators. Therefore the total running time is
> $O(n^3)$.

Comment: Use `$\sigma$` for $\sigma$.

Comment: @Shaun thanks but can you direct me where I can find such graph construction?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm afraid I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you're overthinking this; the proof is literally just telling you which edges to include.

Say that $n=6$ and $S$ consists of the permutations $\{\color{red}{(1\;2\;3)\;(4\;5\;6)}, \color{blue}{(1\;3\;5)\;(2\;4\;6)}\}$. Then the graph we construct has edges $$\{\color{red}{1\to 2},\color{red}{2\to 3},\color{red}{3\to 1}, \color{red}{4 \to 5}, \color{red}{5 \to 6}, \color{red}{6 \to 4}\}$$
in the color of the first permutation, and edges
$$\{\color{blue}{1\to 3},\color{blue}{3\to 5},\color{blue}{5\to 1}, \color{blue}{2 \to 4}, \color{blue}{4 \to 6}, \color{blue}{6 \to 2}\}$$
in the color of the second permutation.